# Display data using fetch from an endpoint on website / Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, fetch

So,i have a http://localhost:3000/community endpoint on node server that in case of calling GET method it shows me 3 different objects with informations about an "user".
For example :

```
[
  {
    "avatar": "http://localhost:3000/avatars/avatar1.png",
    "firstName": "Mary",
    "lastName": "Smith",
    "position": "Lead Designer at Company Name"
  },
  {
    "avatar": "http://localhost:3000/avatars/avatar2.png",
    "firstName": "Bill",
    "lastName": "Filler",
    "position": "Lead Engineer at Company Name"
  },
  {
    "avatar": "http://localhost:3000/avatars/avatar3.png",
    "firstName": "Tim",
    "lastName": "Gates",
    "position": "CEO at Company Name"
  }
]
```

[image]

The task is not to get information displayed in console but to be displayed in a created section on the website ,in the following way:
[image]

Mary Smith,John Smyth and Maryanne Smytch are the names from the json file,their positions are also in the json file,avatars too.
My problem is,because i am new in javascript and using fetch,how to get this data and put them in DOM? the section should be made dinamically in javascript. I need just a code snipped cause i searched the whole internet and i didnt find how to get data from json separatelly  and put them like an avatar,or header,or textarea or something.
Please help,thanks in advance!
My fetch functions:

```
const sendHttpRequest = (method, url, data) => {
    return fetch(url, {
        method: method,
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
        headers: data ? {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        } : {}
    }).then(response => {
        if (response.status >= 400) {
            return response.json().then(errResData => {
                const error = new Error('Something went wrong!');
                error.data = errResData;
                throw error;
            });
        }
        return response.json();
    });
};

const getCommunity = () => {
    sendHttpRequest('GET','http://localhost:8080/community')
    .then(communityResponse =>{
        console.log(communityResponse);
    }).catch(err =>{
        console.log(err,err.data);
    });
}
```

Community route from server:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const {randomNumber} = require('../utils');
const FileStorage = require('../services/FileStorage');


/* GET /community */
router.get('/', async function(req, res) {
  try {
    const result = await FileStorage.readJsonFile(`community/${randomNumber(1, 3)}.json`);
    await res.json(result);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    res.status(500).send('Internal error');
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map inside the response array and append the data to the body like this :

```
for (let i=0;i<items.length;i++) {
 // appending your elements to the body :
 document.body.appendChild(items[i]);}
```

and you can manipulate DOM like this:

```
var node = document.createElement("LI");                 // Create a <li> node
var textnode = document.createTextNode("Water");         // Create a text node
node.appendChild(textnode);                              // Append the text to <li>
document.getElementById("myList").appendChild(node);
```